# javascript sort array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

My array isn't being sorted properly. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
...
 sortArray = new Array ("hello", "Link to Google", "zFile", "aFile");

//sort array
        if (dir == "asc") { 
            sortArray.sort(function(a,b){return a - b}); 
        } else { 
            sortArray.sort(function(a,b){return b - a});
        }

        for(var i=0; i<sortArray.length; i++) { 
            console.log(sortArray[i]);
        }
```

the log is showing them in the same order as they were entered.

Comment: @Tim Cooper's answer is the only one you need.

Comment: of course you can also do this handy little shortcut .......................................................... `(sortArray.sort())[(dir === 'asc' ? 'reverse' : 'slice' )]()`

Comment: @mVChr: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pF2Gv/1/)**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to make a comparison in your sort, not a subtraction:

```
if (dir == "asc") {
    sortArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();
        return a === b ? 0 : a > b : 1 : -1;  
    });
} else {
    sortArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();
        return b === a ? 0 : b > a : 1 : -1;  
    });
}
```

I also used `toLowerCase()` so that 'Link to Google' is placed appropriately.

EDIT: Updated to fix comparison issue according to [comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476736/javascript-sort-array/5476833?noredirect=1#comment16743050_5476833)

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/pF2Gv/)

Comment: I accepted yours for the toLowerCase() add on...though everyone deserves a +1.

Comment: This answer does not seem to work in Chrome. The comparator function is supposed to return 0 if a and b are equal, a positive integer if a should be sorted to a higher index than b, and a negative integer if a should be sorted to a lower index than b.

Comment: @Mike is right.  This should be:

    if (a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase()) { return 0 }
    else { return a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1 }

Comment: @Mike && digant-c-kasundra I updated to fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to sort by subtracting strings, to which you'll get `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, obviously I misread the docs on that one - : D

Answer (score 7):

The trouble is that "a - b" is treating the strings like numbers, which returns NaN. You will get the behavior you are looking for (assuming you are looking for case-sensitive sorts) if you replace your sorts with:

```
    if (dir == "asc") { 
        sortArray.sort(function(a,b){return a < b ? -1 : 1}); 
    } else { 
        sortArray.sort(function(a,b){return b < a ? -1 : 1});
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Your comparator functions returns `NaN`, since it receives two strings, and performs subtraction, an operation that isn't well-defined on strings.

What you should have is something more like:

```
function(a,b){
   return a>b? 1 : (a<b ? -1 : 0);
}
```

or you can use `localeCompare`:

```
function(a,b){
   return a.localeCompare(b);
}
```

Remember to treat case appropriately, e.g. `"L" < "a"` whilst `"l" > "a"`