# Order by Sort Javascript

Tags: javascript

can you help me? ... I have a Array in Javascript and I need order Ascending, my problem is ... I need order only the first number ... "-" to left ....

This is my Arrya ...

```
["20140615-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/ORBTHZK/image_ORBTHZK.gif", "20140617-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/ORBITHCITY/image_ORBITHCITY.png", "20140601-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/423445/image_423445.gif"]
```

And I need This ...

```
["20140601-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/423445/image_423445.gif", "20140615-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/ORBTHZK/image_ORBTHZK.gif", "20140617-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/ORBITHCITY/image_ORBITHCITY.png"]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript sort array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476736/javascript-sort-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough, calling `sort()` on the array works just fine.  here's a copy of what I did in my node console:

```
var arr = ["20140615-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/ORBTHZK/image_ORBTHZK.gif", "20140617-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/ORBITHCITY/image_ORBITHCITY.png", "20140601-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/423445/image_423445.gif"];

arr.sort()

[ '20140601-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/423445/image_423445.gif',
  '20140615-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/ORBTHZK/image_ORBTHZK.gif',
  '20140617-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/ORBITHCITY/image_ORBITHCITY.png' ]
```

Might be different depending on your environment, but it's supported in Node as well as all major browsers.  So if you're targeting some old/edge case browser YMMV.

Comment: Note that a plain `sort` will sort lexicographically. That means `"1000-a"` will be place before `"9-a"`, because `"1"<"9"`. However, if all the numbers have the same number of digits, this will work and will be the fastest way..

Comment: Agreed, and good point.  While his example array isn't affected by that, I should have pointed it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function sortArr(arr, f, isNum) {
    var l = arr.length,
        data = new Array(l);
    for(var i=0; i<l; ++i)
        data[i] = [f(arr[i]), arr[i]];
    data.sort(isNum
        ? function(a,b){ return a[0]-b[0]; }
        : function(a,b){ return a[0]<b[0] ? -1 : a[0]>b[0] ? 1 : 0; }
    );
    for(var i=0; i<l; ++i) arr[i] = data[i][1];
}
var arr = ["20140615-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/ORBTHZK/image_ORBTHZK.gif", "20140617-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/ORBITHCITY/image_ORBITHCITY.png", "20140601-http://localhost:8080/PROYECTO/upload/423445/image_423445.gif"];
sortArr(arr, function(str){ return str.split('-')[0]; }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although calling `sort()` is enough in this case (see @Paul's answer), you can create your own sorting function easily:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a.split('-')[0];
    b = b.split('-')[0];

    if (a > b)
      return 1;
    if (a < b)
      return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

See example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBKn8/1/). You can read more about `Array.prototype.sort()` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).